# Adjusting page or limit from last.fm api in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, last.fm

I`m Student
I am using current last.fm Developer api at java eclipse.
But the problem occurred during use.
I wanted metadata values of a large amount.
But result is only 50 pieces.
I know that the default value is 50. 
So, I have adjusted Page or limit but the result still shows 50 pieces.

What is reason?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String key="#########";
    String tag = "ballad";
    int limit = 100;
    int page = 2;
    int i = 1;

    Chart<Artist> I3 = Tag.getWeeklyArtistChart(tag, page, key);
    Iterable<Artist> tag3 = I3.getTopArtists(page, key);


    for (Artist artist : tag3) {
        System.out.println("["+i+"]"+""+artist.getName());
        i++;
    }
}
```

result

[1]Drake
[2]Ellie Goulding
.
.
.
.
[50]One Direction

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), first post some of your codes so we can help you.

Comment: @010100110110100101101101 What?, I don't put the `Korean` word in there, I just fix his capitalization and spaces.

Comment: +I'll attach code to help you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the default is `"50"` and always `"50"`, because you don't even set or use the items per page limit. see [`chart.getTopArtist(page, limit, api_key)`](http://www.last.fm/api/show/chart.getTopArtists)

You need to add item per pages limit in:

```
Iterable<Artist> tag3 = I3.getTopArtists(page, limit, key)
```

Full Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String key="#########";
    String tag = "ballad";
    int limit = 100;
    int page = 2;
    int i = 1;

    Chart<Artist> I3 = Tag.getWeeklyArtistChart(tag, page, key); // You can also set the limit here. (optional)
    Iterable<Artist> tag3 = I3.getTopArtists(page, limit, key); // Try to add the limit here. (optional)(Default 50)


    for (Artist artist : tag3) {
        System.out.println("["+i+"]"+""+artist.getName());
        i++;
    }
}
```